# Using the bind function to process a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to convert a `String` of numbers (e.g. `"2 3 9 10 14"`) into a list of `Maybe [Token]`.  I have the following code where the function `parseToken` converts a `String` into a `Maybe Token`.

```
data Token = Num Int 

parseToken :: String -> Maybe Token
parseToken str = fmap Num (readMaybe str)
```

For converting the `String` into a list of `Maybe [Token]`, I have the following code below:

```
tokenise :: String -> Maybe [Token]

tokenise str = do
            let (x:xs) = words str
            y <- parseToken x
            ys <- parseToken xs 
            return (y:ys)
```

I am trying to use the `bind` (`>>=`) function to do this. Initially I convert the string into a list of strings, using the `words` function. I then apply `parseToken` to the first element of the list, with the result (i.e. the Token value) of this stored in y.
However, I am not sure how I can apply parseToken to the rest of the list using bind. In general, if one wants to apply a function to every element of a list, while taking in the context of failure, and then join the results into a new list - 
 what is the best way to do this?
Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Are you really calling `parseToken xs`? Looks like a type error to me

Comment: Do you need to use `>>=` specifically, or are you just looking for something cleaner? Because there’s `tokenise = mapM parseToken . words`.

Comment: @Ry- With `mapM parseToken = foldr (\x ms -> parseToken x >>= \t -> (t:) <$> ms) (Just [])` if one insists on using `>>=` :-)

Comment: I'm really not sure what the question is here. But if it is to rewrite the function using `>>=`, actually it already uses it, because that's what `do` notation translates to, by a very straightforward mechanical process.

Comment: mapM has the type declaration of Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]. But how does the final result evaluate to Nothing and not Maybe [Token] if for any one of the elements in the list, parseToken gives a result of Nothing?

Comment: @ceno980 `Nothing` is a value of the type `Maybe [Token]`

Comment: what would be the reason for wrapping a [Token] inside Maybe? what would be the semantic difference between Nothing and Just [] for you?

Comment: @UriBrecher I don't know about for the OP, but for me, I'd want `Just []` to mean I successfully lexed a file that had no tokens, and `Nothing` to mean I had failed to lex the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have merged two separate concerns in one function here:

1. Separating a string into components, and
2. turning each component into a token.

That's all fine and normal so far. What I would recommend, though, is splitting step (2) out into a separate function, and implementing your top-level thing in terms of it. So:

```
parseTokens :: [String] -> Maybe [Token]
parseTokens [] = ...
parseTokens (x:xs) = ...
```

I think you will find it easier to implement this than implementing `tokenise` wholesale, because when it comes time to deal with `xs`, you will find that you already have a function that does the thing you need on it. I recommend taking a stab at implementing this function; if you have trouble, then perhaps a fresh question with your attempt and why you believe it's not possible to make progress on it would be warranted.

Once you've done that, you can drop this function in place in your existing `tokenise` implementation:

```
tokenise str = do
    let (x:xs) = words str
    parseTokens (x:xs)
```

Of course, at this point there's no reason to pattern match on the result of `words` like that, since you just plan to pass on the result anyway:

```
tokenise str = do
    let xs = words str
    parseTokens xs
```

Most people would then inline `xs`,

```
tokenise str = do
    parseTokens (words str)
```

drop the superfluous `do`,

```
tokenise str = parseTokens (words str)
```

and make it point-free.

```
tokenise = parseTokens . words
```